# Frames Support with Titan DB 0.9.0-M2

Tags: cassandra, graph-databases, titan, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

I would like to use Titan 0.9.0-M2 for a feature that it offers over 0.5.4 but I am using Frames heavily and it looks like the `TitanGraph` class no longer implements the Tinkerpop Graph class. Without this, you cannot make a `FramedGraph` from a `TitanGraph` nor can you use `MigrateGraph`.

Any suggestions? Is there a reason why a Graph Database framework built on TinkerPop is no longer implementing their classes? Is there any support for using the basic Frames API with Titan or has Titan implemented some support for this elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Looks like the Titan 0.9.0-M2 API is implementing the TinkerPop3 classes. The namespace has changed to `org.apache.tinkerpop` and there is currently not mention of Frames, only Gremlin in the 3.0.0-incubating release. Looks like I'm gonna have to make due with 0.5.4.